# Checkbox functionality inside popover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to develop a popover login form using bootsrap.I have a checkbox in the popover,  I can not impelment an onClick functionality to the check box inside the popover.The same function is working fine outside the popover,Please advice me.

**Demo:** [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/najurudeen/D3VP9/)

**The entire Script**

```
 <script>

      $(function() { 
       $('.popover-markup>.trigger').popover({
    html: true,

    title: function () {
        return $(this).parent().find('.head').html();
    },
    content: function () {
        return $(this).parent().find('.content').html();
    }
});



$('#vehicleChkBox').change(function(){

    if($(this).attr('checked')){
          $(this).val('TRUE');
     }else{
          $(this).val('FALSE');
     }

    alert($(this).val());

});  

      });
    </script>
```

**The html part**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->


  </head>

  <body>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <br>

    <br>
<div class="popover-markup" data-placement="bottom"> <a href="#" class="trigger" data-placement="bottom">Popover link II</a> 
    <div class="head hide">Lorem Ipsum II</div>
    <div class="content hide">
    <form role="form">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="control-label">E-Mail</label>
                  <input class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="hello@example.com" type="text">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="inputPassword" class="control-label">Passwort</label>
                  <input class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="******" type="password">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">

                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Login</button>

                </div>

                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-8">
                    <div class="checkbox">
                      <label>
                        <input  id="vehicleChkBox" type="checkbox"> Remember me
                      </label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">

                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-link  pull-right small" onClick="remember_me()">Register new Account</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </form>

    <div class="footer hide">test</div>

</div>

  </body>
   <script>

      $(function() { 
       $('.popover-markup>.trigger').popover({
    html: true,

    title: function () {
        return $(this).parent().find('.head').html();
    },
    content: function () {
        return $(this).parent().find('.content').html();
    }
});



$('#vehicleChkBox').change(function(){

    if($(this).attr('checked')){
          $(this).val('TRUE');
     }else{
          $(this).val('FALSE');
     }

    alert($(this).val());

});  

      });
    </script>

</html>
```

Please guide me.

Comment: There is a `checkbox` inside your popover. Could you please elaborate on your question ?

Comment: Do you want to call a javascript function on clicking the `checkbox` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend using on click.  Also, you will have to apply the binding on the body element.  Then monitor explicitly for the the specific element in which triggers an action such as the checkbox (vehicleChkBox) or button.

The reason why the element was not bounded was because the element was not visible to be bounded on.

```
$('body').on('click', '#vehicleChkBox', function(){
   window.alert('I was clicked');
});
```

**Updated Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/D3VP9/4/

Answer (score 0):

If your having trouble with a checkbox, use a div and add an onclick function

```
<div id="uniqueID" onclick="yourFunction()"></div>


<script>
    function yourFunction() {
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `onchange` instead of `onClick`.
`onchange="myFunction()"`
Then inside the `myFunction()` you can check the state of the checkbox and act accordingly.